# Shorthand animation is not working in my css sheet

Tags: css, animation

I have this code and I'd like to use the shorthand of animation but its not working.

```
.box-thank-you__container .leads-container {
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: fadein;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    /*animation: fadein 0.3s ease-in forwards;*/
}
```

This is my keyframe code:

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I have comment the animation shorthand because its not working. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Add your fadein animation's keyframe code as well or more detail

Comment: yes do share the keyframes code too.. as the current shorthand is right so there maybe issue with the keyframe code.

Comment: Ive shared the keyframes code as well. See above.

Comment: Please find below answer. It's working fine. If you expect different output then please describe that

Comment: That is working, but the shorthand on the other hand not. Is that because I am using two keyframes?

Comment: Works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ce75pa2j/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I have increased `animation-duration` for more visibility Please check this:

```css
.box-thank-you__container .leads-container {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: fadein;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    /*animation: fadein 0.3s ease-in forwards;*/
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-thank-you__container">
  <div class="leads-container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>

</div>
```

As per your updated code please check below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/fusp34y2/

Comment: Ow forgot to say I am using 2 keyframes. But the shorthand in this keyframe (fadein) is not working